# Instead of Overriding , Remove a method when extending class?

Tags: python, methods, mask

Let say I have :

```
 class A:
    def m1(): ...

 class B(A):
   # def m1(): ..doesnt work later, has to be masked
   def m2() :...      

 class C:

    def __init__(..):
       self.ab = <A or B>

    def abc():
       if hasattr(self.ab, 'm1') : ...
       elif hasattr(self.ab, 'm2') : ...
```

if I define m1() in B I'm overriding it.
What I want instead is to delete it or mask it in such a way so that hasattr(Bvar, 'm1') returns False.

m1() and m2() do different things, and can not share a name, but B should not have m1()...

Comment: Feeling like you need to remove a method is a good sign that you don't actually have a subclass. Is there really a "is a" relationship here? Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: Your edit further strengthens my first comment. If `B` should not have `m1()` then it shouldn't be a subclass of `A`. (Either that, or _`A`_ shouldn't have `m1()`.)

Comment: A general rule in OOP - You can't override a method and make it less accessible then the original method.

Comment: i know its no good OOP, but they share functionality anyway .. better mess one method rather than the rest ;( .. may be I can make it 3 lvl hierarchy...

Comment: "they share functionality anyway" isn't a sufficient argument for subclassing. If one "isn't" the other, you don't have proper subclasses.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* do this by implementing `__getattribute__` to raise an error:

```
In [1]: class A():
   ...:     def m1(self):
   ...:         return 42
   ...:     def m2(self):
   ...:         return 'foo'
   ...:
   ...: class B(A):
   ...:     def __getattribute__(self, attr):
   ...:         if attr == 'm1':
   ...:             raise AttributeError("Can't access m1 on B object because design is broken")
   ...:         return super().__getattribute__(attr)
   ...:     def m3(self):
   ...:         return 0
   ...:

In [2]: b = B()

In [3]: b.m1()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-06964da3db13> in <module>
----> 1 b.m1()

<ipython-input-1-72beff581825> in __getattribute__(self, attr)
      8     def __getattribute__(self, attr):
      9         if attr == 'm1':
---> 10             raise AttributeError("Cant access m1 on B object because design is broken")
     11         return super().__getattribute__(attr)
     12     def m3(self):

AttributeError: Cant access m1 on B object because design is broken

In [4]: b.m2()
Out[4]: 'foo'

In [5]: b.m3()
Out[5]: 0

In [6]: hasattr(b, 'm1')
Out[6]: False
```

However, this fundamentally implies that `B` **should not** inherit from `A`. Your design is broken. It breaks the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). You should almost certainly address that before relying on a hack like this. But it's possible.

Be careful implementing `__getattribute__`, because it is easy to get infinite recursion